# Continuity Of Complex Valued Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Consider the following complex valued function:
$$f(z)=(2+z)Arg(z)$$
Does $f(z)$ have removable discontinuities?

(Note: $Arg(z)$ denotes the principal argument.)

The following is my approach:

We know that $Arg(z)$ is not continuous for $z\in \Bbb R^-$ and it has no removable discontinuities.

$\Rightarrow f(z)=(2+z)Arg(z)$ also has no removable discontinuities.

Is the above argument correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument has the right idea, but it is unclear how you are deducing the last step.  Why must $(2+z)Arg(z)$ have no removable discontinuities just because $Arg(z)$ has no removable discontinuities?  For instance, notice that $f(z)=1/z$ has no removable discontinuities, but $zf(z)$ does have a removable discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: I realised the mistake. Infact I have solved the question. The above function has exactly 1 removable discontinuity at the point -2